# When to use /opt? When to use /usr/local/ instead of /usr/ when creating Debian package

Tags: linux, package, debian, filesystems, deb

I'm creating a package that will not be part of an official Debian distribution (it is proprietary, no source code), but will be available from a privately-hosted repository. I would like to follow the Debian packaging instructions for file placement, and I need some help finding the right document.

According to the [Packaging Manuals](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/fhs/fhs-3.0.html), "add-on application software packages" goes in `/opt` while `/usr/lib` is for packaged applications and `/usr/local/bin` is for local software. I'm looking for a definition of these terms that explains how to categorize third-party applications installed by a local administrator using packages.

I'm not looking for *opinions*, but for definitions/instructions in the official documentation. I've spent some time reading things but believe there is something I've missed since it seems certain that there are explicit directions.

If you believe that any location is fine for any software (but there may be different opinions), please answer the underlying question by saying something along the lines of "There are no clear rules because the documentation is inconsistent."

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question; I agree now it is not primarily opinion-based and have voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Debian packaging manuals (the policy, developer-reference, etc) nor the FHS, are really very clear on this, I guess for the former mostly because they are not concerned with packages that are not intended to be included in the distribution, as those policies/best-practices cannot easily be enforced there. They are currently only commented in passing as part of its reference to the FHS, and the Debian intended support for third-party and local software.

This is mostly a matter of conventions though. But what is relevant here is dpkg's behavior, as it assumes control of the filesystem, and will overwrite present but untracked files on the filesystem if they get also shipped in a `.deb` package. So the convention is that the distribution leaves */opt* and */usr/local* alone, as a guarantee to let third-party projects or the local admin use those as they see fit.

The */opt* hierarchy is conventionally used by unpacking say third-party tarballs, or running some ad-hoc installer that places stuff there.
The */usr/local* hierarchy is conventionally used by building projects locally and installing them there directly, or by directly adding local scripts. These are covered somehow in the FHS.

In the end what really matters is that there will be no pathname clashes. So if you are packaging your software as `.deb`s then dpkg will honor those, and you could place the objects under */usr* (which I'd say is the expected location for packaged projects, regardless of them being part of Debian or not). Of course if you feel uncomfortable with that, you could still place them under */opt* (*/usr/local* seems definitely wrong), as long as you have control over the systems involved and what might end up there, f.ex.

This probably needs to be spelled out explicitly in the Debian manuals and/or the FHS, and I might take a stab at doing that in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It help me to have someone confirm that the instructions do not explicitly cover my situation and that I haven't missed something obvious.